# CodeIgniter's file upload library ignores allowed_types?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, file-extension

I tried to upload a certificate file and failed:

```
$config["allowed_types"] = "cer";
$this->load->library("upload", $config);
$this->upload->do_upload("fieldname");
```

I always get the following error, even if I upload a .cer file:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed
```

That is a lie, I uploaded a file of an allowed type!
Why does this class ignore its [documented](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) setting allowed_types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the mime type in `mimes.php` config file. It should be something like this:

```
'cer' => array('application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

Location of mime: application/config/mime.php

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to upload csv's when they'd been generated by excel - in the end I had to use an extended list of mime types to allow the files to be uploaded. I've done a quick search for .cer mime-types and got two candidates, try using:

```
 $config['allowed_types']  = 'cer|application/x-x509-ca-cert|application/pkix-cert';
```